# svnsync I cant sync my repo because i got error: Could not read chunk size

Tags: svn, svnsync

I want to sync only my branch in repo. `branches/my_branch` so I executed:

```
svnsync init http://localhost/svn/my_branch http://remote_svn/branches/my_branch
```

After thet I executed:

```
svnsync sync http://localhost/svn/my_branch

[...]
Copied properties for revision 53542.
Committed revision 53543.
Copied properties for revision 53543.
Committed revision 53544.
Copied properties for revision 53544.
Committed revision 53545.
Copied properties for revision 53545.
Committed revision 53546.
Copied properties for revision 53546.
Transmitting file data .........................................................
.................................................svnsync: E175002: REPORT of
'http://remote_svn/branches/my_branch': Could not read chunk size: connection 
was closed by server (http://remote_svn)
```

(of course there ware MUCH more 'dots')

I know that this revision is HUGE because it's initial.

So is there any way to do this other way? Maybe checkout (checkout works fine) it in temp place and manually commit into destination SVN and then resume it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your network or the server closed the connection on you. You can try again, keeping an eye on the memory usage of the sync process.

To fudge it manually, you'd need to copy the data from the files directory, then carefully edit the contents of property file 0. In there you'll find the details of the sync process. Once you've copied the first file delta across, you just edit the 0 property to read like its already synced this file. (ie add 1 to the relevant entries). Take a little time to understand each of the entries in that property file though. If you make a mess of it, you just delete the sync directory and start again (or copy the entire sync repo and restore it)

Comment: I checkout that 53547 revision from `SOURCE` into temporary folder (somewhere), when moved all files into checkouted `DEST` folder without `.svn` files. I could do that because rev.53547 is initial/creating branch revision. I will accept Your answer but I got problem with date of commit. How can I change it ? SVNSYNCH can do that so maybe I can ?

Comment: dol this on the rep itself, look in the db folder for the internals. that's what svnsync is syncing. It does not do a checkout. If you want to change the date of commit, edit the properties for the revision.

Answer (score 0):

With newer versions of svnsync you can do the following.

On source machine

```
svnadmin dump repo > repo.dump
```

On machine where you want to sync to

```
svnadmin create repo
svnadmin load repo < repo.dump
```

then

```
svnsync init --allow-non-empty <dest> <source>
```

and it will assume that the first n revisions that you dumped are the same on dest and source.